# Подсчитать количество строк в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Создаю скрипт личной почты пользователей.
Реализовал вывод новых сообщений запросом:

```
$MailUS=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE `id_komu` = '$us[users_id]' AND `wread` = '0' GROUP BY id_us ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10");
while ($MSGuS = mysql_fetch_array($MailUS))
{
echo "My CODE";
}
```

с помощью этого кода я вывожу непрочитанные сообщения для пользователя. Как видите в запросе присутствует *GROUP BY id_us*- что позволяет вывести автора сообщения всего один раз.
Но мне нужно сделать еще листинг страниц, а для этого мне нужно подсчитать сколько человек написало пользователю, для этого я создал такой запрос:

```
$MailUSC=mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mail` WHERE `id_komu` = '$us[users_id]' AND `wread` = '0' GROUP BY id_us"), 0);
```

но он не правильно считает. 
Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таком случае можно выбрать все уникальные значения поля от кого (`id_us`)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id_us`) FROM mail 
WHERE id_komu= '$us[users_id]' AND wread= '0'
```

Подробнее про `DISTINCT` читайте [здесь](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/DISTINCT_optimisation.html)

Или можно вложенным запросом, но это будет ресурсозатратнее.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( 
    SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE 
    id_komu = '$us[users_id]' AND `wread` = '0' 
    GROUP BY id_us
) as tbl
```

Comment: спасибо огромное. опять выручили!